# return data as cursor from function in pl/sql wiithout create type oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, cursor

I wrote this code in pl/sql but I couldnt take answer.

```
  create or replace function mostafa.sbs_Topic_LedgerBalance8Column
   (BranchID number,DateFrom number,DateTo number) 
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
  IS  O_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;

  BEGIN
  open O_RESULT for
     Select s* From Mostafa.topic ;


      RETURN O_RESULT;

end sbs_Topic_LedgerBalance8Column;
```

and I called it this way:

```
DECLARE v_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
v_refcursor :=mostafa.sbs_topic_ledgerbalance8column(12,12,12);

FOR employee_rec IN v_refcursor
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         employee_rec.ID);
   END LOOP;
end;
```

why did I get error when I retrieve result?

error is :v_refcursor is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: Saying that you "get error" but not telling us what error or where you're getting it doesn't help us much.  There are a few syntax errors in your function but I'm guessing that you've introduced those in posting your question.  You haven't told us the definition of the `topic` table.  What exactly are you trying to avoid?  Are you trying to avoid declaring a variable of type `topic%rowtype`?  Or trying to avoid declaring a new type?

Comment: It's not allowed to use cursor variables(`v_refcursor`) in the for cursor loop. Use simple `loop .. end loop`  and `open, fetch, close` constructs to read from that cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a refcursor, you can't access it by using the cursor for loop. Use something like the following instead (Untested):

```
DECLARE
    v_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_emp_rec topic%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    v_refcursor :=mostafa.sbs_topic_ledgerbalance8column(12,12,12);

    LOOP
        FETCH v_refcursor INTO v_emp_rec;
        EXIT WHEN v_refcursor%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec.id);
    END LOOP;
    close v_refcursor;
END;
```

Comment: thanks to reply .The result of function is not type of Topic table.Can I get data without create type?

Comment: No, the result of the function is a refcursor. But the elements inside the refcursor are of the type of a row in your topic table as you select * from the table topic. If you only select the columns ID and NAME, then you have to FETCH v_refcursor INTO v_emp_id, v_emp_name.. or something like that